# Conditional display mode for entity reference field

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

i am having a paragraph with 2 fields :

- Slider : field_gallery_slider    / Booléen
- Images   : field_gallery_image   / Référence à une entité media

How could i change the media display mode if the slider is selected ?

```
      //the current code
      {{ content.field_gallery_image }}
         //code that would call the image with another display mode than the one choosen for the entity
       {% if content.field_gallery_slider|field_value|render=="1" %}
           //smthlike {{ content.field_gallery_image|slider }}
       {% endif %}
```

Comment: I would do this with a custom theme hook: `MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_paragraph_alter` based on your Boolean value. So if the boolean value of `field_gallery_slider` is true, then render a different template for your gallery slider. If you have tons of fields that need to be unique per view mode, then you'd need to use `hook_entity_view_mode_alter` and then within that you need to do the view mode switch based on your boolean value.